Query parameters are removed from Primary navigation extension page
I would like to open a new primary navigation page from context menu of a page in experience space UI.
Something like :
https://www.cms.com/ui/custom-primary-navigation?pageid=tcm:16-123-64
So that I can get page uri.
But when my custom page is loaded query parameters is been removed and I am not able figure out how to solve it.

Current API doesn't support query parameters as part of extended route. We will consider adding it in the next releases.
Navigation service filters out any unsupported queries\routes on application load or during any navigation.
